# Rendering XHTML as MS Word Document - Headers

Tags: xhtml, ms-word

I generate an XHTML document and set the Mime type as "application/msword" so it opens in Word.

To create a header I appear to have to reference an *external* file thus:

```
<style>
   ...
   @page{mso-footnote-separator:url("**OUT_files/header.htm**") fs;
   mso-footnote-continuation-separator:url("OUT_files/header.htm") fcs;
   mso-endnote-separator:url("OUT_files/header.htm") es;
   mso-endnote-continuation-separator:url("OUT_files/header.htm") ecs;}
   @page Section1{
      mso-header-margin:.5in;
      mso-header:url("OUT_files/header.htm") h1;
   }                }
   ...
</style>
```

Does anyone know how to reference a div defined within the main XHTML document itself, without having to reference an external file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

MS Word is quite locked down.  I was not able to get this to work with a non-external file, but it seems to make sense.  The values being "included" are repeated in the display.  It's not possible to have "hidden" divs and refer to them (at least, not when I was trying), so not sure how to get this to work properly.

For me, I ended up just creating a simple Macro that would handle this for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are very lucky, a data: URL might work, maybe, in Word 2007?  I haven't tried that myself, but MS introduced partial support for data: URLs in IE8.